# css styled radio button not work because of background image

Tags: html, css, background, radio-button

I am using styled css radio button from http://www.csscheckbox.com/

The problem is they give the radio button height manually (i.e. 30px) and the text spills over the next line.

[image: Isuse image]

So I tried to remove manual height. Then as the background image is used as background position there is more problem :(

[image: More problem]

Background image used here is like following img.

[image]

Here is the css script for the radio button.

```
input[type=radio].css-checkbox {
    display:none;
}

input[type=radio].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left:35px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:30px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;

}

input[type=radio].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
    background-position: 0 -30px;
}
label.css-label {
    background-image:url({{ URL::to('/') }}/application/assets/img/checkbox.png);
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

Here is Markup.

```
<ul>
     <li><input type="radio" name="answer2671" id="radio12344" class="css-checkbox" value="1" /><label for="radio12344" class="css-label radGroup1">Planning and strategy</label></li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="answer2671" id="radio12345" class="css-checkbox" value="2" /><label for="radio12345" class="css-label radGroup1">Supporting your teammates</label></li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="answer2671" id="radio12346" class="css-checkbox" value="3" /><label for="radio12346" class="css-label radGroup1">Motivating everyone</label></li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="answer2671" id="radio12347" class="css-checkbox" value="4" /><label for="radio12347" class="css-label radGroup1">Courage in the face of adversity</label></li>
  </ul>
```

Any form of help is appreciated!

Comment: including your markup would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height, line-height and add some top and bottom padding to the label.

```
input[type=radio].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
padding:20px 0 20px 35px;
display:inline-block;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
font-size:20px;
vertical-align:middle;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: sorry it didn't help. radio button is showing like third image I shared on the post.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to his:

```
ul {
    width:240px;
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:5px 5px;
    margin:5px 0 20px;
    line-height:15px
}
input[type=radio].css-checkbox {
    display:none;
}
.quiz-question-block.qhidden {
    display:none;
}
input[type=radio].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left:45px;
    height:32px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:30px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=radio].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}
label.css-label {
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLQO2.png');
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

You'll need to adjust to your needs, I also limited the width of the form for visualization purposed, but you'll get the idea

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/1539td4t/)

**EDIT:** another option is to modify the image and make it bigger in height, with a big separation between both states, and simply adjust the CSS to the new image size

Comment: It looks good on fiddle. What's the main difference with my code?

Comment: you need to adjust the `LI` element and from there you adjust the `INPUT` element because you're positioning with relation to the containing block element (in this case, a LI, but it could also be a DIV).

Comment: then your option is to modify the image and make it bigger in height, with a big separation between both states, and simply adjust the CSS to the new image size

Comment: Can you change answer with the last comment? I will gladly accept it as answer.